# pulling button to the bottom in a semantic ui sidebar

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui to layout a sidebar.

The following example shows a sidebar with a button pushed to the bottom using `positioning:absolute`. Is there an ideomatic way to arrange this in semantic-ui without the need of custom styles? The class `bottom` does not apply for buttons.

```
<div class="ui very thin styled sidebar active">
  <div class="ui fluid vertical icon buttons">
    <div class="ui facebook button">
      <i class="facebook icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui twitter button">
      <i class="twitter icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui google plus button">
      <i class="google plus icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="ui repeat button" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px;">
      <i class="reorder icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was searching the same thing. I don't think it's supported even though it would make for a nice addition especially for the smaller sidebar with icons in it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527261/pulling-button-to-the-bottom-in-a-semantic-ui-sidebar#

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is no native `semantic-ui` (v2.2.2<) means to do that.

You may place the *repeat* button at the bottom of the sidebar adding a `flexbox` container:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and then groupping *social media buttons* in one child element (with default styles), and the *repeat button* in the other:

```
.bottom-aligned {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/akhanov/3e83bkbu/)